# Custom Timer Job does not Execute

Tags: custom-timer-job

I have a custom timer job that loads items into a generic list. The timer job is not executing. The timer job is deployed and the feature is activated. I can see the Timer job in the Job Definitions and in the Scheduled Jobs but it never shows up in the Job History.

I have tried invoking it manually and through powershell but it just does not want to fire.

This timer job has been deployed to 2 separate farms and worked but on the new farm it is not executing. We also have other custom timer jobs on this farm which is working fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you reset the time job service?

Comment: What do the ULS logs say at the time that they are due to run?

Comment: What happens if you start it manually in the Job Definitions section? Is the status "failed" or "success"?

Comment: I have cleared the cache of the timer job and restarted it. I cant find any logs in ULS regarding the timer job. When starting it in Job Definitions it does not start. It does not show in history so I cant see the Status and it does not show a Last Run value.

Comment: However running the Execute method from powershell. The timer job does what it should but it does not dhow up in Job Definitions as registering a run.

Comment: Is the timer job using the farm account to run, or which account is it using?

Comment: can you post here the code where you set schedule? It might be set wrong so timer job is not executed, because "it's not the right time".

Comment: Sounds to me like it could working correctly and this behavior is based on the SPJobLockType

Answer (score 3):

Could you debug the timer job locally in your dev enviornment. Remember to restart the timer service in your dev enviornment before you attach to the owstimer service from Visual Studio.
If you can successfully attach and debug locally ensure the url to the site and list are the same in your UAT/PROD enviornment.

Hope this helps

Comment: why do we have to restart the OWSTimer service, is this a good practice?

Comment: After deploying your code (new/updated) you need to restart your timer service for new changes to take affect. Timer jobs are very stable they can b rerun and scheduled